# How we can launch the Chrome browser in iphone device using appium for testing

Tags: appium

We want to write appium automation scrips for chrome browser of IOS device. currently the browser is getting launched but it does not perform any activty on the chrome browser . could you please help me to fix it.

Comment: Do you have the script what you have written ? What is the error ? 

I have just written a chrome browser (but this is for Android) and it is working perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome bundle ID for the DesiredCapabilities (app) > **com.google.chrome.ios**

If you have done it already, please put here your script for better helping.